# Variation of the proof of Cauchy Schwarz from MultiVariable Calculus text

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This proof comes from vector-calculus by Jerrold Marsden and Anthony Tromba.

let $a = y \bullet y$ and $b = -x \bullet y$. If $a = 0$ we have the trivial case.

Now

$0 \leq (ax+by) \bullet (ax+by) = a^2x \bullet x + 2abx\bullet y + b^2y\bullet y$ .
Now the author states that this previous line is equal to 
$(y \bullet y)^2(x \bullet x) - (y \bullet y)(x \bullet y)^2 $. This is where I am confused and if anyone can elaborate on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is $\bullet$? What are $a,b,x,y$?

Comment: the dot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}\color{red}{a^2}(x \bullet x) + 2\color{red}{a}\color{blue}{b}(x\bullet y) + \color{blue}{b^2}(y\bullet y)&=\color{red}{(y\bullet y)^2}(x\bullet x)+2\color{red}{(y\bullet y)}(\color{blue}{-(x\bullet y)})(x\bullet y)+(\color{blue}{-(x\bullet y)})^2(y\bullet y)\\&=(y\bullet y)^2(x\bullet x)-2(y\bullet y)(x\bullet y)^2+(x\bullet y)^2(y\bullet y)\\&=(y \bullet y)^2(x \bullet x) - (y \bullet y)(x \bullet y)^2 \end{align}

Comment: This i perfect thanks